# mysql group by but only group if second row is the same

Tags: mysql

im wondering what the smartest way is to group my mysql results... I have the following table structure:

```
- id
- userId
- status (values from 1-100)
```

Lets say with the following content:

```
1 | 1 | 10
2 | 1 | 10
3 | 1 | 15
4 | 2 | 15
5 | 3 | 10
```

Now I want to group all results by user but only for each status. So the results im looking for should be:

```
1 | 1 | 10
3 | 1 | 15
4 | 2 | 15
5 | 3 | 10
```

Hope you understand want im looking for...

Best
Tassilo

Comment: Why keep '1' instead of '2'? Also, if you want the smartest solution then you have to show the various solutions being considered, so that we can advise on the smartest.

Comment: that doesnt matter :)

Comment: do you actually need the id? group by userId, status is all you need and in mysql you can have the id in the select fields, anyway.

Comment: would be better, but right now im also happy without it

Comment: If the id doesn't matter, then why would its inclusion be 'better'. That makes no sense !?!

Comment: but if I group by userId, there are no different statuses for this user any more... not?

Comment: because im forming an array out of those ids, and i can access more row info afterwards if i like

Comment: grouping by userid and status will give you exactly the output you asked for

Comment: alright, trying it now - ive been sure it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the id, then a GROUPing query is needed; this will produce the results you shown:

```
SELECT MIN(id), userId, status
FROM your_table
GROUP BY userId, status
;
```

If you don't need the id, then GROUPing is not the best tool, use DISTINCT instead; like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userId, status
FROM your_table
;
```

Answer (score 0):

The topic of this question say "Group only if next row is the same" in that case I would do something like this:

```
create table USER_(id integer, UserId integer, status integer);

insert into USER_ values(1,1,10);
insert into USER_ values(2,1,10);
insert into USER_ values(3,1,115);
insert into USER_ values(4,2,115);
insert into USER_ values(5,3,10);
insert into USER_ values(6,1,10);

select min(a.id)as id, a.userId, a.status ,count(*) from USER_ a join USER_ b 
on a.userid = b.userid and a.id = b.id-1 group by a.userId,a.status;

 id | userid | status | count 
-----+--------+--------+-------    
  1 |      1 |     10 |     2
```

If I look at the explanation for the question here then, I would do something like this:

```
select min(a.id) as id, a.userId, a.status  from USER_ a 
group by a.userId,a.status order by a.userid,status;

 id | userid | status 
----+--------+--------
  1 |      1 |    10
  3 |      1 |    15
  4 |      2 |    15
  5 |      3 |    10
```

Please correct if I have a wrong understanding of the question